# AJAX call returns page HTML / doesn't hit Page Method is ASP.Net (no MVC or Json)

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am updating a tool for my current company that provides basic product layout documents depending on choices picked.  Recently it appears a bot of some sort has been hitting the toolbox periodically, and after some discussion with the company we built the toolbox for we have decided to add the ReCaptcha tool to the page.

The way the toolbox was setup is ASP.net without the use of Json or MVC (the toolbox is a fair few years old, built long before I joined the team).  Adding the ReCaptcha tool was not an issue, I did it without a plugin using a window.onload function and using their instructions.  This was all done on the options.aspx page, the code for the ReCaptcha call is in the options.aspx.cs page.

To reach this code I am attempting to do an AJAX call where the form would normally be submitted.

**The issue:**  Each AJAX call returns the HTML of the page, and the Page Method (VerifyReCaptcha) does not trigger when I have a break point in it.  I need it to call the method which will do all of the listing, then simply pass back a string that simply says if it was a success or not.  It doesn't seem to matter what dataType or contentType I enter (if any), or if I run it as POST or GET.

Here is the code of the button that calls the function for the ajax call.

```
    <input type="button" id="DownloadLayoutButton" value="Download Layout" class="navigationButton" style="width: 200px; height: 24px;" />
```

Here is the function that is called.

```
    $("#DownloadLayoutButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "options.aspx/VerifyReCaptcha",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                challenge: Recaptcha.get_challenge(),
                response: Recaptcha.get_response()
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Success") {
                    alert("Success!");
                else
                    alert("ReCaptcha entry was incorrect!");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
```

This code never seems to hit the VerifyReCaptcha() method that is on the options.aspx.cs page, the method is as follows. As stated I have tested and confirmed that this function works on its own.  Previously I had it returning a boolean value but since ajax can't work with booleans, I changed it to return "Success" or "Failure" depending on the result.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string VerifyReCaptcha(string challenge, string response)
    {
        try
        {
            string PRIVATE_KEY = "MY_KEY_HERE";
            string remoteip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify");

            byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("privatekey={0}&remoteip={1}&challenge={2}&response={3}", PRIVATE_KEY, remoteip, challenge, response));

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;

            request.GetRequestStream().Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);

            String resultString = String.Empty;
            String errorString = String.Empty;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                resultString = sr.ReadLine();
                errorString = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            Boolean b;
            b = Boolean.TryParse(resultString, out b) && b;

            if (b)
                return "Success";
            else
                return "Failure";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Failure";
        }
    }
```

The aspx page is using the following sources.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check your console on the Network part (Chrome -> F12, Network), what is the status of the request?

Comment: If I add ", status" to the success function and check it it comes back as "success".  Not that seems to help since a breakpoint in the method itself is never hit.

Comment: What about the console? Do you get a 200?

Comment: No errors in the console unless I change the URL away from options.aspx/VerifyReCaptcha.  See my second comment on the answer from Karl Anderson below for those errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your ASP.NET AJAX Page Method needs to be `static`.

You have:

```
public virtual string VerifyReCaptcha()
```

It needs to be:

```
public static virtual string VerifyReCaptcha()
```

Note: Read [Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/) for more information.

Comment: Sorry I forget to change that back, but thank you for pointing it out.  I have modified the original question to reflect it as static (with the challenge and response being passed in through the AJAX call).  The issue still happens exactly the same even with VerifyReCaptcha as a static method.

Comment: So if you use any browser tools (F12 for IE, Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools), what is the message in the console when the page loads and the page method does not execute? HTTP 500? HTTP 400?

Comment: In Chrome if I put a breakpoint on "if (result == "Success")" and put a watch on result then I get the HTML of options.aspx back as my result.  No error is thrown and the result is not returned.

If I set the URL to just VerifyReCaptcha I get an error of "POST http:localhost/Website/VerifyReCaptcha 405 (Method Not Allowed)".

If I put the URL as /Options.aspx/VerifyReCaptcha the error is "Post http://localhost/Options.aspx/VerifyReCaptcha 404 (Not Found)".

The path to the page is http://localhost/Website/Options.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, asp.net WebMethods expect posted data in JSON. 
In your JavaScript jQuery Ajax call use `dataType: "json"` rather than `dataType: "text"`.

I also add  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` as another option.

The WebMethod is not called if the doesn't find the correctly formatted data it expects.

Comment: I attempted to add Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the project but when I tried to load the page after adding it I got an error.  It read "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."  Do you have any recommendations for what to do about this, I am not very familiar with Json.  Here is the link to the version I downloaded: http://json.codeplex.com/downloads/get/287841

Comment: You don't need Newtonsoft.json to use WebMethods, nor did you write any JSON yourself. Just make the changes I suggested. If you want to use Newtonsoft for somethine else, you have to download the correct version. It seems you used the 4.0 version while your site is .net 3.5

Comment: The reason I was asking is because I had tried using both the dataType of json and contentType of application/json; charset=utf-8 previously without it working.  However I went back and added it, the results are that the ajax function now goes into the error method instead of success with the Response returning the HTML of the page still and the status as "parsererror".  It is still not hitting the VerifyReCaptcha method.